# Extended Partition

Tags: linux

In Linux can we make two extended partitions? and if not then how can we make use of the remaining un-allocated space in the scenario stated below:

Suppose I have added a virtual hard drive of 100 GB
to my OS.
Now I have made three primary partitions of size 10 GB each. After that I have made my 4th partition as Extended Partition and assigned it just 20GB memory.
Then using that memory of Extended partition, I have created two more Logical Partitions of 10 GB each.

Now, as per original size of Hard drive and adding the allocated size of hard drive into partitions. I have made use of 50GB in total.

How can I now make use of remaining un allocated 50 GB partition?

Or it will be now totally impossible to do so??

Comment: Why not make the extended partition larger? Or move on to GPT already...

Comment: I think it is possible, although I am not sure that you can configure it with fdisk. However, that extended partitioning thing is an ancient fossil, if you want well configurable volume management, use LVM.